How to remove interaction error on pycord?
How fix error interaction? I asked ChatGPT, but he led me in circles.
My code:
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="t.", intents=intents)

servers = \[1249591729171071077\]

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user} is ready and online!")

@bot.slash_command(description="Приветствие от бота")
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Привет! Я бот Discord!")

@bot.slash_command(guild_ids=servers, name="ping", description="Отправляет задержку бота.")
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Pong! Задержка составляет {bot.latency} мс.")

bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))

change from ctx.send to ctx.respond()

Welcome to StackOverflow, can you also include your error traceback?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If you answer your own question, put it as an answer to your question and not in the question itself. It's clear that that's what you're trying to do as you answered it yourself in change from ctx.send to ctx.respond(). However, this is something easily answerable by the documentation and is most likely a duplicate.

This question is similar to: Pycord Slash command Respond with Embed. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In order to fix this, you will have to change ctx.send to ctx.respond, or else the command will error out. Discord Application Commands of which slash command are part, require you to respond to the interaction. So if you use ctx.send you will just send a message in the channel, without responding to the interaction.
Also, you are setting the command_prefix="t." parameter in your bot, even tough it is never used since you are using slash_commands.
If you still want to send a message, but don't want the error, you can also respond in ephemeral. You can see my example below:
import os

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="t.", intents=intents)

servers = [1249591729171071077]


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user} is ready and online!")


@bot.slash_command(description="Приветствие от бота")
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.respond("Command processed!", ephemeral=True)
    await ctx.send("Привет! Я бот Discord!")


@bot.slash_command(guild_ids=servers, name="ping", description="Отправляет задержку бота.")
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.respond("Command processed!", ephemeral=True)
    await ctx.send(f"Pong! Задержка составляет {bot.latency} мс.")


bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))

